# Python: Finding matching elements in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, compare, tuples

I have been trying to compare elements in a list to find a matching pair. It looks something like this.

```
 hand=[(2, "Club"), (4, "Heart"), (2, "Diamond"), (5, "Club"), (8, "Spades)]
 if hand.count(0) ==2:
   print(true)
```

I just wanted to test it out to see if I could find the amount of times it appears in the list but it just prints out none. Shouldn't it print out true since 2 of Diamonds is there as well?

Comment: `hand.count(0)` counts the number of times `0` appears in the list `hand`, which is 0 times. Note sure why you are getting None, but obviously, it's because `0` is not in your list...

Answer (score 0):

`list.count(element)` counts the number of times element occurs in list. By giving `element = 0`, you end up counting the number of times 0 occurs in the list.

What you will need to do instead is

```
for card in hand:
    hand.count(card) > 1:
        print("Found a pair of: ", card)
```

This loops over the cards in the hand, and checks to see if there is another one in the list. If it is there it prints out that it found a pair.

Comment: Oh wow, I guess I live up to my username haha. I thought count(0) would return the amount of times that the position 0 of the list shows up.

Comment: Don't even worry about it, we've all been there. =)